# ArcGIS Pro SDK user authentication

Tags: authentication, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am developing some tools using ArcGIS Pro SDK, how could I authenticate users who use my tool. Our organization has AD accounts, and Esri accounts are based on those AD accounts.